# How to access filesystem of app container while running container tests in Quarkus?

Tags: containers, filesystems, quarkus

When running native tests in Quarkus, the application runs in a container. I have functionality that involves reading and writing to the filesystem. Therefore, I must prepare test data before each test run by writing the desired files to the filesystem.

For regular `QuarkusTest`, this works fine, as everything runs locally. When running a native `QuarkusIntegrationTest`, this obviously will not work. The container running my native image has its own filesystem, and the data that I do prepare in my test runner will end up on the container host machine.

It would be really neat if one could map a volume for integration testing, but as far as I know, this is not possible. Another option is to create a REST API for testing purposes to write and read files. But this would need to be specifically secured.

What would be a feasible way to prepare test data on the filesystem of the app container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibilty to mount a volume for a container test will be available with Quarkus 3.5
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35864

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your resources for them to be available to your native executable.

The attribute you're looking for is

```
quarkus.native.resources.includes
```

I would enable the include for the test profile.

```
#Replace with what works for your use case:
%test.quarkus.native.resources.includes=/data/cfg/**/*.txt,/config/**
```

Refer to https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus.native.resources.includes for more details.

Comment: Yes, but this are static recoures. I need to be able to clean and regenerate new testdata for each test